# Azure Load Balancer Get Originating Client IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I am using the Azure Standard Load Balancer (client -> external lb => firewall => internal lb => server), when my api request gets to the server I need to be able to identify the originating clients ip address.

I have tried to use X-Forwarded-By and some other request headers but it looks like they're either not supported or have been stripped.

I have not been able to find any documentation online pertaining to the issue - does anyone know how I can access the client ip address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the LB for a HTTP backend. Thus, its important to understand what LB does - and what not. There are many good articles out there if you search of "azure load balancer vs application gateway". [Here](https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-application-gateway-load-balancer-front-door-and-firewall/) is one example which sums it up well:

> The Load Balancer is a TCP/UDP load balancing and port forwarding
>   engine only.  **It does not terminate, respond, or otherwise interact
>   with the traffic**.  It simply routes traffic based on source IP address
>   and port, to a destination IP address and port.

Thus, it does not add anything to your HTTP headers etc.

So, LB is more like a router than a proxy. If you want the latter, I suggest you look at Azure Application Gateway. This, btw, can include Web Application Firewall. So you might be able to reduce three components into one.